# Adding New Facebook pixel to <head>

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, head

Trying to add the **new** Facebook pixel to Magento 1.9.1.1.  So it can appear on all pages.

I have added the following to app/design/frontend/rwd/CustomTheme/layout/local.xml between

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
      <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/facebook.js</name></action>
      </reference>
    </default>
  </layout>
```

also tried

```
<reference name="head">
  <action method="addJs"><script>js/facebook.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

and have added the following **NEW** Facebook pixel to js/facebook.js

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '1111111');
fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1111111&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

It fails to load the Facebook pixel in my source code?  What have done wrong?

How do you add any script to the **head** area otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at using [google tag manager](https://tagmanager.google.com/#/home) to handle this so when the script changes or you want to add more scripts to the site its all done in the one place.

If you still want to add the script yourself you should not use a js file and create a block instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
      <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="facebook.pixel" as="facebook.pixel" template="page/facebook-pixel.phtml" />
      </reference>
    </default>
  </layout>
```

and then in `skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}/js/facebook.js`
add your js code.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with google tag manager.  But I did try `<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>skin/frontend/rwd/CustomTemplate/js/facebook.js</name></action>` and `<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/facebook.js</name></action>` but it still does not load `facebook.js`.   Would it be problematic to place FB pixel in the `app/design/frontend/rwd/CustomTemplate/template/page/html/head.phtml`?

Comment: Actually just realised the facebook pixel shouldn't be included in a js file as it does some other things, I've just updated my answer on how to add it to a template file

Comment: I will give that a try. But, what is wrong by placing FB pixel in `app/design/frontend/rwd/CustomTemplate/template/page/html/head.phtml`?

Comment: makes it easier to manage, imagine if you have like 10 different scripts for tracking conversion etc the head.phtml can become very clustered.

Comment: It makes sense.  So I copied the **Facebook Pixel Code** to `facebook-pixel.phtml` and placed it under `app/design/frontend/rwd/CustomTemplate/template/page/'.  Also copied the `facebook.js` to `skin/frontend/rwd/CustomTemplate/js/`.  Also added `<reference name="head"><block type="core/template" name="facebook.pixel" as="facebook.pixel" template="page/facebook-pixel.phtml" /></reference>` to `local.xml` in `<default>` area.  it still does not show up!

Comment: you'll need to change the reference name to `content`

Answer (score 1):

Check out: https://github.com/erfanimani/EI_FacebookScripts

It uses a block/template with the script tag and injects it into the head. You can't use `addJs` because there's variables that need to be injected into the script (using PHP).

Answer (score 1):

To make new FB pixel tracking work you need to touch on the different sections  of your website -:

Here are the steps to implement the tracking correctly

Step 1

The following piece of code will go in the head section of your theme

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '1150333754569860');
fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1150333754569860&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

You can implement the above using **default** layout handle with reference **head** because this needs to be rendered in the head section of your website for all pages.

Step 2

The following piece of code will go in the search and advanced search section of your theme

```
fbq('track', 'Search');
```

You can implement the above using **catalogsearch_result_index** layout handle with reference **content**.

Step 3

The following piece of code will go in the product detail section of your theme

```
fbq('track', 'ViewContent');
```

You can implement the above using **catalog_product_view** layout handle with reference **content**.

Step 4

The following piece of code will go in the cart section of your theme

```
fbq('track', 'AddToCart');
```

This can be done as part of your event or observer using **checkout_cart_product_add_after** event

Step 5

The following piece of code will go in the wishlist section of your theme

```
fbq('track', 'AddToWishlist');
```

This can be done as part of your event or observer using **wishlist_product_add_after** event

Step 6

The following piece of code will go in the wishlist section of your theme

```
fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');
```

This can be done as part of your event or observer using **customer_register_success** event

Step 7

The following piece of code will go in the checkout section of your theme

```
fbq('track', 'InitiateCheckout');
```

You can implement the above using **onepagecheckout_index_index** layout handle with reference **content**.

Step 8

The following piece of code will go in the order confirmation section of your theme

```
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '1.00', currency: 'USD'});
```

You can implement the above using **checkout_onepage_success** layout handle with reference **content**.

Step 9

The following piece of code will go in the checkout review section of your theme

```
fbq('track', 'AddPaymentInfo');
```

This can be done as part of your event or observer using **sales_quote_payment_import_data_before** event layout handle with reference checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before

If you are a magento developer then the above information should be enough for you to implement new FB pixel tracking. If not then the following is the recommended

https://www.scommerce-mage.co.uk/magento-facebook-conversion-audience-tracking.html

Comment: You really did a great job here, can you add payment info to your answer as well?

Comment: I added Step9  to your answer for your review.

Comment: I already gave you :)