# addtocart pixel after add to cart event happened

Tags: magento-1.9, facebook

I am trying to inject a pixel to the webpage when addtocart event happens, however I am not sure how to do it. there are different ways which came to my mind:

1-make an observer and add a handle to the layout and the handle has a phtml file which has the pixel inside it:
I tried this solution but I get an error when I try

```
Class Scosche_Facebook_Model_Observer {

    public function appendAddToCartPixel(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
       $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
          $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle("handlename");
    }
}
```

the layout for some reason is null and I am not sure why I cannot get the layout.

I know that I should listen to

> controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after

so that I can get the layout but I also should listen to checkout_cart_product_add_after so I am a bit confused.

2- make an observer and just put the pixel right over there:

```
Class Scosche_Facebook_Model_Observer {
    public function appendAddToCartPixel(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $html = <<<HTML
    <!-- Begin Facebook AddToCart Pixel -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        fbq('track', 'AddToCart');
    </script>
    <!-- End Facebook AddToCart Pixel -->
HTML;
        return $html;
    }
}
```

This does not do anything either, Although I am sure the function runs. I also used a simple echo but when I checked page source view it was not there, here is config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Scosche_Facebook>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Scosche_Facebook>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <scosche_facebook>Scosche_Facebook_Model</scosche_facebook>
        </models>
    </global>
        <frontend>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <scosche_facebook>
                        <class>Scosche_Facebook_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>appendAddToCartPixel</method>
                    </scosche_facebook>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        </events>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <facebook>
                        <file>facebook.xml</file>
                    </facebook>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
</config>
```

and here is the Observer:

```
Class Scosche_Facebook_Model_Observer {

    public function appendAddToCartPixel(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
???????
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to do this. I tried steven answer on this link:
[Adding New Facebook pixel to <head>](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93069/adding-new-facebook-pixel-to-head)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` is dispatched in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php` like this :

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after', array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product));
```

So, there is no chance that `$observer->getEvent()->getLayout()` returns something else than `null`.

If I were you, I will try this :

1) in your observer, just set a flag in session :

```
public function appendAddToCartPixel(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
   Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setFacebookPixel(true);
}
```

2) Use a layout to add a template `facebook-pixel.phtml` on every page  :

```
<default>
    <reference name="after_body_start">
        <block type="core/template" name="facebook.pixel" as="facebook.pixel" before="-"  template='path/to/your/template/facebook-pixel.phtml'/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

3) In the template `facebook-pixel.phtml`,  display your script if the flag is present.

```
<?php if( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getFacebookPixel()):?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        fbq('track', 'AddToCart');
    </script>

    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->unsFacebookPixel()
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: You are really smart, thank you for this.